# Error: Unrecognized selector sent to instance when I try to click on my TableView cell

Tags: ios, swift

***EDIT***

I can only click on one cell of my tableview in the simulator. If I click one cell (It doesn't matter which one), and then I click on any another cell, the app crashes.

Here's the error I get when I click on the second cell of my tableview:

> Thread 1: Exception: "-[Goals_V2.FieldTableViewCell field:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f95b68100c0"

Here's the code:

**FieldTableViewCell.swift**

```
class FieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    static let identifier = "FieldTableViewCell"
    
    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "FieldTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var field: UITextField!
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        field.placeholder = ("What would you like to do today")
        field.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("\(textField.text ?? "")")
        return true
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        var allowsSelection: Bool { true }
    }
}
```

**FirstViewController.swift**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.register(FieldTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: FieldTableViewCell.identifier)
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        
    }

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FieldTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! FieldTableViewCell
        
        return cell
    }

}
```

**Screenshot of what the tableview looks like**

*If I click on one cell, it works fine, but if I click on another cell afterwards, the app crashes*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6baf.jpg

**Full Stack Trace of Thread 1**

*The one highlighted in blue is where the exception breakpoint caught the exception.*
I had to take two screenshots of the full stack trace since it wouldn't fit on my screen, but the image links from top to bottom

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdXsX.jpg

**Back Trace in Debug Console**
*This is what I receive in the debug console when typing `bt` after the `(lldb)` in the debug console*

````
    frame #0: 0x00007fff51253982 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x00007fff23e5eb94 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    frame #2: 0x00007fff49354af0 UIKitCore`-[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 302
    frame #3: 0x00007fff23e4286c CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 1436
    frame #4: 0x00007fff23e44b58 CoreFoundation`__forwarding_prep_0___ + 120
    frame #5: 0x00007fff49326c1d UIKitCore`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    frame #6: 0x00007fff48cd5baa UIKitCore`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 223
    frame #7: 0x00007fff48cd5ef2 UIKitCore`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 396
    frame #8: 0x00007fff49632d69 UIKitCore`-[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 155
    frame #9: 0x00007fff49353dae UIKitCore`-[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 358
    frame #10: 0x00007fff496329af UIKitCore`-[UITextField _finishResignFirstResponder] + 48
    frame #11: 0x00007fff49353e89 UIKitCore`-[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 140
    frame #12: 0x00007fff49632829 UIKitCore`-[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 93
    frame #13: 0x00007fff49353ae2 UIKitCore`-[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 661
    frame #14: 0x00007fff49816d52 UIKitCore`-[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 145
    frame #15: 0x00007fff4963163e UIKitCore`-[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 182
    frame #16: 0x00007fff495e19c6 UIKitCore`-[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessaryActivatingSelection:] + 195
    frame #17: 0x00007fff495c869f UIKitCore`-[UITextSelectionInteraction _checkForRepeatedTap:gestureLocationOut:] + 275
    frame #18: 0x00007fff495c9245 UIKitCore`-[UITextSelectionInteraction _handleMultiTapGesture:] + 1103
    frame #19: 0x00007fff49326c1d UIKitCore`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    frame #20: 0x00007fff48e21b4f UIKitCore`-[UITextMultiTapRecognizer onStateUpdate:] + 169
    frame #21: 0x00007fff48eb6358 UIKitCore`-[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 44
    frame #22: 0x00007fff48ec02ba UIKitCore`_UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 109
    frame #23: 0x00007fff48ebcb89 UIKitCore`_UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 295
    frame #24: 0x00007fff48ebbeda UIKitCore`-[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureForActiveEvents] + 760
    frame #25: 0x00007fff48ead9cb UIKitCore`_UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 2745
    frame #26: 0x00007fff48eaced4 UIKitCore`-[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 467
    frame #27: 0x00007fff48eacc5c UIKitCore`-[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:] + 225
    frame #28: 0x00007fff49364277 UIKitCore`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4479
    frame #29: 0x00007fff4933e6d1 UIKitCore`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
    frame #30: 0x00007fff493c94ce UIKitCore`__dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 7628
    frame #31: 0x00007fff493cc692 UIKitCore`__handleEventQueueInternal + 6584
    frame #32: 0x00007fff493c2f35 UIKitCore`__handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 88
    frame #33: 0x00007fff23da1c91 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    frame #34: 0x00007fff23da1bbc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    frame #35: 0x00007fff23da1394 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    frame #36: 0x00007fff23d9bf8e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 974
    frame #37: 0x00007fff23d9b8a4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    frame #38: 0x00007fff38c39bbe GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 139
    frame #39: 0x00007fff49325968 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 1605
  * frame #40: 0x0000000107645c2b Goals V2`main at AppDelegate.swift:12:7
    frame #41: 0x00007fff520ce1fd libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #42: 0x00007fff520ce1fd libdyld.dylib`start + 1```

If you need any more information or context about my project, let me know and I'll do my best to elaborate. Also, this is my first Stack Overflow question/post so if I'm not following certain etiquettes or something like that, please do let me know. Thank you so much for your help!
````

Comment: Can you edit your question adding a screenshot of the full stack-trace for thread 1? It should be automatically opened when you encounter with a crash, else you can open it by tapping ⌘ + 7. Also try to add one `Exception Breakpoint` for debugging. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: @SauvikDolui I added the screenshot of the full stack-trace for thread 1 near the bottom of the question. I also added a bit more specificity to the problem I'm having. Thanks!

Comment: https://imgur.com/JCXG1Fx does not show the top section of the stack, can you try to post another one taking it from the top of the stack if you are still struggling with it?

Comment: @SauvikDolui I added a better picture, does that help? I also added the backtrace, I figured that could maybe be helpful. The new picture link is in the same place as it was before, under the heading Full Stack Trace of Thread 1 near the bottom. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'd suggest you uploading your demo to the github. It's really hard to tell what could be wrong.

Comment: I have the same problem with a UITextField added to the footer view of a UITableView. This could be a new iOS bug related to first responder handling within table view.